# Create attribute using Data Patch in Magento 2

Tags: category-attribute, magento2.4.4

Trying to create `Category` **Attribute**, But getting an error.

> foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in
> Magento_Root/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Patch/PatchRegistry.php on
> line 144.

And my code is below.

```
<?php

namespace VLCSolutions\CategoryAttribute\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallCategoryAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * Category setup factory
     *
     * @var CategorySetupFactory
     */
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * Initialization
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
    )
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getDependencies() method.
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getAliases() method.
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        // TODO: Implement apply() method.
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();
        $setup = $this->moduleDataSetup;

        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(Category::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

        $menu_attributes = [
            'md_temp_special' => [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'MD Temp Specials',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 10,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information'
            ]
        ];

        foreach($menu_attributes as $item => $data) {
            $categorySetup->addAttribute(Category::ENTITY, $item, $data);
        }

        $idg =  $categorySetup->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, 'General Information');

        foreach($menu_attributes as $item => $data) {
            $categorySetup->addAttributeToGroup(
                $entityTypeId,
                $attributeSetId,
                $idg,
                $item,
                $data['sort_order']
            );
        }

        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }

}
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix those 2 methods

```
    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it's worked.